# jQM when closing dialog or navigating back, the event gets triggered again

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, triggers

I'm making a mobile application with jQuery Mobile. It's going well but there is one major issue I can't resolve.

I have single index.html with several pages (data-role=page). I call these pages with click events in my javascript since I pass parameters. The pages consist of listviews which are created (live pagebeforeshow) from a json file (based on the parameters).
For instance, on the categories page, you click a certain category, it's ID gets passed to the next page which displays the subcategories of this category in a new list.

Now the strange thing is that often, not always, when I click the back button, or when I close a dialog, the click event that opened that page or that dialog, gets automatically triggered again.
For instance, you click an item in the list. The click event triggers a dialog to pop-up. You close the dialog, the list (previous page) gets reloaded and immediatly the dialog pops up again as if the click event gets triggered again... very strange.

I have no clue.

This is an example of an event I use to tell the browser to get the json and display what I need.

```
$('#dialog_zin_nl').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event, data) {
```

*here comes all the code that has to happen on this page like getting the right json stuff and appending it to the html...

after that (inside this 'pagebeforeshow') I declare my button click events like this

```
$("#execute_sub_rubriek").on("click", ".selected_zin_nl", function(event){
                    var selected_zin_nl  = $(this).attr('selected-zin-nl');
                    $.mobile.changePage( "#dialog_zin_nl?current_rubriek=" + current_rubriek_id + "&current_sub_rubriek=" + current_sub_rubriek_id + "&current_zin=" + selected_zin_nl + "", { role: "dialog"} );
                  });
```

If anyone ever came across this same problem or knows what's wrong. Please explain me.

Thanks!

*EDIT* If I use pageinit I don't have this problem. Though I cannot use pageinit since the content of the page has to be refreshed when a user choses another category for instance.

A thought of mine: is it possible to call pageinit if the page gets called by the back button and pagebeforeshow if the page is called by another button?

Answer (score 2):

You're adding an `on` listener in the event `pagebeforeshow` and since `pageshow` fires when you navigate back to the page it will add a **second** `on` listener and that's why your code is behaving oddly.

You need to separate your `pageinit` and `pageshow` code, think carefully pageinit should only initialize a page, pageshow gets called everytime a page is viewed, so if you have dynamic content you should be refreshing your DOM there, but attach your `on` listeners in your `pageinit` so it only ever happens once.

Here's a link to a similar question which highlights how we cleaned up our JS on our jQM site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368352/737023 - if you organize it this way it makes a lot more sense - especially keeping track of what fires when and what runs when.