# Jquery mobile: how to debug?

Tags: php, debugging, jquery-mobile

I have some problem, i guess, in my jquery mobile pages, but i cannot find the problem. Firebug doesn't fire any error, or even warning. Chrome's console idem. The only symptom is that some, not all, of my pages doesn't load. I can only see the loading animation of a circle keeping to turn on itself...

In general, i have an index page, containing 15 pages like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header" class="ui-bar-b">
    <h1>Yea</h1>
</div>
<?php include 'page1.php'; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>
```

The first three work like a charm, the other cause problems. Now the code of each page is in a separate php page. I tried also to load the other pages separately but no errors...

I'm using jquery mobile 1.1.1 and jquery 1.7.1.
Please help me.

Comment: does everything work ok if you turn off ajax navigation?

Comment: how do i? i'm a bit new to jquery ^^'

Comment: hi, try this page in the jquery mobile docs: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness: finally i solved the problem. There was a div unclosed in a page. The interesting part is that the page i could not load was not the one owning the error, but the subsequent!!
Seems so obvious now, but if javascript and php does not fire error, the only spot which to look is html! I validated the code with this and caught the error. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options
Thank you all for the useful information!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to debug you shouldn't have your JS on every page, you should be loading JS either  all at the entry point or using RequireJS to load them on demand based on what page you navigate to. This way you can also put breakpoints on all your JS and debug easily.

If you include JS on each page it needs to be within your `<div data-role="page"/>` tags, this is because jQM uses AjAX loading and you probably have JS in your `<head/>` that's not being pulled in.

If you need help organizing your JS see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368352/737023

Comment: good article, i'll try to do such a thing. At this time, i have avery page separated, containing its own js code and include within a div data-role page. It can be that this is the cause for which the compiler does not fire errors?

Comment: Not sure about why you're not getting errors, you're saying loading some pages directly doesn't work? Sounds like you're just missing an include or the proper jQM containers - feel free to dump one of these pages in a jsFiddle

Comment: Next time i'll try to solve the problem, i'll do it immediately. Sometime i feel the problem it is not in the pages, for if i try to move the entire block div data page in the index, the page moved works, but another begin to do not. And this happens in an amazing, apparently random, way. It drives me crazy... At the present i have 12 pages and 7 working, the remaining not. I decided to keep filling the pages, for some of them are still mock up of the final pages, then i'll try to see what is going on, and then i'll fill a complete jsfiddle. I think this is the only way. :)

Comment: Hmm try this, assuming you have separate PHP files for each page, and the JS is properly inside the `<div data-role="page">` run your code within (run this immediately after the script tag - no doc.ready you don't use that in jQM) `jQuery("div:jqmData(role='page'):last").bind('pageinit', function(){`

This way when you navigate to the page, the right code fires. If you don't do this you get issues because multiple pages exist in the DOM at once, broad selectors blow up $('div.myClass') may hit more than one page

Comment: Also don't load any code that runs in the head, just libraries. Move that code into the page div

Comment: finally i could test your solution but didn't work. I'm still in the darkest night of the programmation ^^'